# Firebase Realtime Database Cache behaviour on Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to understand how Firebase Realtime Database uses cache. The documentation doesn't clarify some cases about cache handling. Especially for Flutter, there is no documentation and online sources are not enough. There are two different scenarios that I'm confused.

First of all, I start with setting the cache for both scenarios:

```
await FirebaseDatabase.instance.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
await FirebaseDatabase.instance.setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes(10000000);
```

**Scenario 1:** I listen to the value of a specific user.  I want to donwload user data for once. Then, always use cache and download only updates if there is any:

```
final stream = FirebaseDatabase().reference().child("users").child("some_id").onValue();
```

It's my understanding that Firebase will download the node first and use the cache later if there is no update. This won't change **even if the app restarts**.

**Scenario 2:** I want to query the posts that are created only after the date:

```
final date = DateTime(2020,6,20);
final data = await FirebaseDatabase().reference().child("posts").orderByChild("createdAt").startAt(date).once();
```

Here for Scenario 2, I'm not sure how cache will be done. If Firebase Realtime Database caches the query, will it download everything when a new post created after the date? Or  it will download only the new post and get others from the cache?

Comment: Look at this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59723877/flutter-firestore-reset-cache

Read this medium doc
https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firestore-clients-to-cache-or-not-to-cache-or-both-8f66a239c329

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a change to a location/query that you have a listener on, Firebase performs a so-called delta-sync on that data. In this delta-sync, the client calculates hashes on subtrees of its internal version of the data, and sends those to the server. The server compares those hashes with those of its own subtrees and only sends back the subtrees where the hashes are different. This is usually quite a bit smaller than the full data, but not necessarily the minimal delta.

Note that Firebase will always perform a delta sync between the data it has in memory already for the query/location and the data on the server, regardless of whether you enable disk persistence. Having disk persistence enabled just means the in-memory copy will initially be populated from disk, but after that the delta-sync works the same for both cases.

Comment: So, it downloads only updated data regardless of my query. You're also saying that Firebase always sends and downloads hashes to sync data. Maybe this will be a different question, but it is very important. You know Firestore initially downloads everything from server and counts one document read even if there is no updated data when we register a listener, but Firebase Database doesn't do that. When you compare Firestore and Firebase Database in terms of cost of realtime updates, which one is more affordable?

Comment: Firestore has a completely different mechanism to load data, a different API, a different wire protocol, and a different pricing model. I recommend using the [pricing calculator](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) to compare which one works out cheaper for you, as it depends almost solely on your use-case and the way you implement it. One thing is common though: developers seem to run into the quota limit of their free project sooner on Firestore than on RTDB.